# Handling log files across mulitple Windows Servers

Tags: powershell, logging, server, windows-server-2008

I have an application that at any time could be running on 1 of 4 **windows servers**. Hence, if I am looking for a specific log item, it could be in any of the 4 log files. What I am looking to do is find a solution where I only need to look in one place to find all of the combined logs for each of the 4 servers.

I am looking to do this without a commercial product and also would like to do so without major performance impacts.

Any suggestions based on previous, successful implementations?

I am using log4net to log to a specified file on the server. One solution is to route the log4net logs to MS SQL database however I am worried about performance here. Is there a way to merge the individual files independent of the log4net code?

Comment: Log files? Or Event Logs?

Comment: See my edit for further explanation

Comment: Configure log4net to log to the eventlog, and configure [log forwarding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890.aspx) of the relevant events to a central log server on all 4 application servers. This question belongs on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).